# Creating multiple views with different Models on one page with Backbone boilerplate

Tags: backbone.js

What is the best way to create multiple views with different models using the backbone boilerplate? It seems like things are set up to render individual pages, but not to render multiple resources simultaneously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I am understanding you correctly, but please let me know if I am not. Backbone shines in SPA's (Single Page Apps). I am not saying that it should only be used for an SPA. If you start thinking of views as sections on a single page, I think Backbone starts to make more sense. So when your model updates or changes, the section/view is being re-rendered and not the entire page.

Look at the Trello and read this article http://blog.fogcreek.com/the-trello-tech-stack/ - especially the part on Backbone. I think the above will answer your question more thoroughly.

Tyrone

Comment: You're absolutely right. In hindsight, I didn't ask my question very well. What I really want to know, is what the best way of nesting resources is. In other words, What is the best way to nest a collection within a model. I've been having some real difficulty with this, and none of the resources that I read are proving helpful.

Comment: Are you looking for relational models? This is an excellent resource if that is indeed the case https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational. I guess I am just a little confused, because I embed my models within a collection instead of collection within a model.

Comment: So normally you would embed a model within a collection, but there are times when one module (or resource), is the child of another. Example: We have a book model, and a book collection. Each book model is also capable of containing a collection of pages.

Comment: Did you take a look at the source I posted above about relational models, because I think thats what you are looking for? Backbone does not handle relationships, therefore the above plugin was developed. So you can have a collection that is related to a specific model.